# Redirect a Domain if server is down

Tags: linux, domain, redirection

I am currently searching for a way to redirect users if my server is down.
Is there any way to do such a thing?

Like: If someone wants to connect to my Teamspeak-Server but its offline, it should automatically redirect the user to a Backup-Teamspeak-Server.

Any idea how to realize such a thing?

Comment: I would use [keepalived](http://www.keepalived.org/) It takes 2 servers and 3 ip-nos. Each server has it's own ip, the third ip points to stylers.teamspeekserver.com, keeaplived the makes sure that when your primary server is up it *owns* the 3:d ip and when your primary server goes down the secondary server takes ownership of the 3:d ip.  The details I'll leave to you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think of is setting up an intermediate server which checks the availability of your Teamspeak-Server.

So, the actual URL (say teamspeak.domain.com) would point to a, for example, PHP page on the intermediate server which would check the status of the actual server and redirect the user accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting up a round robin DNS setup.  Many different ways to achieve this but the wikipedia page will provide you with a starting point.

[Round Robin DNS - Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_DNS)

Comment: dns round robin is not going to redirect, it's going to keep insisting on the dead server

Answer (score 0):

I've looked around for a solution for Teamspeak in the past. If i remember correct, [ts3dns](https://www.ts3dns.com/) might me useful for you. I can't remember if it does provide the ability to add 2 records (primary, backup) but you could have a 3rd server checking the availability of your servers and set the dns record to the correct server.

Actually you need a DNS server with very low TTL. That could be ts3dns, no-ip like services or even your own custom DNS server who would also check for the availability and respond accordingly.

Have in mind that since Teamspeak doesn't support load balancing, you can not use the round robin DNS setup because people will end up connected on different servers. For the same reason, your server checker should not change the records back to the primary server once the connection is resolved. If you want to do so, you should also connect to the secondary TS server and reboot it so that all the clients get reconnected to the primary one.

Unfortunately, since i needed something easier that that (without needing a 3rd server or external dns services), i ended up setting up 2 subdomains (ts1.domain.com, ts2.domain.com) for my clan and let everyone know that if the primary server goes down, they should use the 2nd one. They also use the ability to connect on multiple servers so that they would know, when the primary is back online.